# why move up one level while compiling different files of same package

Tags: java

Thanks to stackoverflow i finally understood that i need to compile from the source directory when m trying to compile a file which has a object of another class of the same package declared in one of its method. ex-

```
package p1;
public class accesslevel
{
    int n=2;
    private int pri_n=3;
    protected int pro_n=4;
    public int pub_n=5;
    public accesslevel()
    {
                System.out.print("\nin accesslevel constructor");               
        System.out.print("\nn="+n);
        System.out.print("\nprivate n="+pri_n);
        System.out.print("\nprotected n="+pro_n);
        System.out.print("\npublic n="+pub_n);
    }
}

package p1;
class samepckp1test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        accesslevel a=new accesslevel();
    }
}
```

But i dont get why i need to do that?Can someone help me understand why i need to move one level up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because packages in Java are mapped to directories.

So, if you have a `p1` directory for your `samepckp1test` class like this:

```
p1
   -> samepckp1test.java
   -> accesslevel.java
```

Then java expects you to be on `p1`'s parent directory to compile to compile `p1` package. (`p1` package contains `samepckp1test` and `accesslevel` classes).

If  you want your classes to be in the default package (no package declaration at all which I don't recommend) you can compile them from their container directory (instead of the parent directory in your example).

Rule is: classes are expected to be found inside directories following their package declaration.

That is, if your class `MyClass` is in `com.stackoverflow.test` package, your class source is expected to be found in:

```
com/stackoverflow/test/MyClass.java
```

So you need to be in directory containing the `com` subdirectory.

Comment: Thank you! I guess i get it now.
so if my class Myclass is in the directory stackoverflow and i'm trying to access a file abc.java in package test then my class source is expected to be found in stackoverflow/test/abc.java
Did i get it right?

Comment: @Pablo-Thank you for the prompt reply. I'm starting to like java!